# How to set up type boundaries of AnyRef to make it only case class

Tags: scala, scala-generics

suppose that i have some case classes

```
case class Foo(i: Int)
case class Bar(s: String)
```

i want to define some function that take A : AnyRef as parameter.
But! I want to setup it boundaries with:

1. A is AnyRef but not an Object
2. A is AnyRef but case class only

something like that

def caseClassProcessor[A](A: AnyRef <: Some bounds) = ???

def notObjectProcessor[A](A: AnyRef ! Object) = ???

is it possible any way?

Comment: maybe `Product with Serializable` so it would be `caseClassProcessor[A<:Product with Serializable](a:A) = ???`

Comment: Have you looked at using a typeclass?

Comment: The question is _why_ you need that. There is no practical use for it as far as I can see. It seems like an XY problem

Comment: case classes simply don't have any common supertype other than `Product with Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example is what you need:

```
case class Foo(int: Int)
case class Bar(string: String)

def foo[A](arg: A) = arg match {
  case Foo(int)    => ...
  case Bar(string) => ...
  case _           => ...
}
```